# How to open anchor in a modal window, not a new tab

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, anchor, modal-window

[This site](https://simplesharebuttons.com/html-share-buttons/) demos Social Sharing code such as 'share to Facebook'.  Here, clicking  the links on the left opens the sharing in a modal window.  Their code:

```
<!-- Facebook -->
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=https://simplesharebuttons.com" target="_blank">
    <img src="https://simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" />
</a>
```

I want a similar effect and I have the following `anchor` but this opens in a **new tab**.  I want it to open in a **modal window**:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.idybrand.com/" title="Share on Facebook" target="_blank" >
    <img alt="Share on Facebook" width="40" height="40" src="img/social_media/facebook.svg">
</a>
```

How can I achieve this please?  Possibly using Bootstrap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your code with this::

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.idybrand.com/" title="Share on Facebook" target="popup" onclick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.idybrand.com/','popup','width=600,height=600'); return false;">
<img alt="Share on Facebook" width="40" height="40" src="img/social_media/facebook.svg">
</a>
```

It will work..

Comment: Thanks.  That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @DaveChambers If it helped you please upvote the answer and accept it to help others.

Comment: I can...in 4 seconds - just waiting ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this. I hope it helps.

```
<a onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/','mywindow','width=640,height=360')" href="javascript:void(0)"><button>Click FB</button></a>
```

Comment: Thanks.  That does work but I had to adapt the code slightly so I accepted Rana's answer as that was more 'ready to use'.  But thank you for your help.  I upvoted your answer

Comment: Happy Coding :)

Comment: @DaveChambers Thanks